# Specifying PropertyPath syntax for animation inside GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to perform a rotate animation inside a GroupStyle header on a DataGrid and I cannot get the PropertyPath syntax down for the Storyboard.TargetProperty property. Here's a contained example to highlight my problem

```
<Window x:Class="ImageRotateTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <x:Array Type="sys:String">
        <sys:String>One</sys:String>
        <sys:String>One</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Four</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Four</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding}" x:Key="ViewSource">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription></PropertyGroupDescription>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewSource}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Three">
                                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Test">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" To="360" Duration="0:0:0.800" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Test" />
                                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="Item" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The result here should be that the group header should spin only for the "Three" group and not any others. However, running this results in the following exception

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in     PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'RenderTransform.Angle'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.
```

I have tried the following for the Storyboard.TargetProperty without success

```
(TextBlock.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)
(RenderTransform).(Angle)
RenderTransform.Angle
```

My question is; How can I refer to the TextBlock.RenderTransform using property path syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code very nearly works as it is. You just need to make one change:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(RotateTransform.Angle)"
```

I have tested it with just the `TextBlock` and can see that spinning away, so if you can't see it spinning in your `DataGrid`, either your `Name` property `Binding` is incorrect, or its value is not the expected `"Three"`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Three">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Test">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="
                                    RenderTransform.(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="360" 
                                    Duration="0:0:0.800" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Test" />
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Hey, your example works fine but the problem is specifically due to  it being in the datagrid group header. The Name binding comes from the CollectionViewGroupInternal object which is the datacontext for the GroupItem and that binding works correctly.

Comment: Are you saying that it *doesn't* work when inside the `DataGrid`?

Comment: When specifically inside the datagrid header, yes.

Comment: Ok, so you're probably getting the *immutable object* error now... that is caused because you are trying to animate an object with a data bound property.

Comment: You're right. I solved the problem with the CloneConverter here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/26/cannotanimateimmutableobjectinstance.aspx. The converter sits on the binding for my DataTrigger `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource CloneConverter}}" Value="Three">`

Answer (score -2):

For Rotation of Object this is simple and best example..

```
<Window x:Class="Animation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Animated Rectangle" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <Image Name="MyImage" Source="e:\a.jpg" Width="100" Margin="50" ></Image>
        <Rectangle
            Name="MyRectangle"
            Width="100" 
            Height="100"
            Fill="Blue">

            <Rectangle.Triggers>
                <!-- Animates the rectangle's opacity. -->
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="MyImage" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:3" 
                                AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Rectangle.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```